# How to add an item in the Collection of an already hydrated entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine, sylius, hydration

In Sylius, translatable entities use an `ArrayCollection` to handle translations, for example `Product` entity has `ProductTranslation` entities in `translations` attribute.

Given an already hydrated entity `$object` from the database we have one item in `$object->translations`.

Now, I want to add another existing translation into my `$object` from the database.

```php
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('o');
        $qb
            ->addSelect('fallback_translation')
            ->innerJoin(
                'o.translations',
                'fallback_translation',
                'WITH',
                'fallback_translation.locale = :fallback_translation'
            )
            ->setParameter('fallback_translation', $locale)
            ->where('o = :translatable')
            ->setParameter('translatable', $object)
        ;

        /** @var TranslatableInterface $translation */
        $translation = $qb->getQuery()->getSingleResult();

        dump($object === $translation); // true
```

With this code, the `$translation` entity is the same as `$object` (same object reference) without the new locale in the collection and I don't understand why. I think it's related to the hydration with Doctrine, but I'm not aware of the logic behind.

My query is OK because if I force the mode `AbstractQuery::HYDRATE_ARRAY`, my array contains the right data. My need is really to have an hydrated object, so updating the existing entity by adding the new translation to the collection of `$object` would be perfect.

Comment: Likely this is one of the issues, either the object is part of your UnitOfWork and Doctrine will avoid refetching it. Try doing an `$em->clear()` or use a new entity manager instance before fetching the data to mitigate this. The other possibility, that I can think of, could be a result cache being used try adding `disableResultCache()` to your query.

Comment: @dbrumann you were right, the `$em->clear()` solved the problem! Leave an answer and I will accept it, thank you!